# Inserção de elementos em uma lista Html

Tags: javascript, html, input

Desejo que ao enviar no input um elemento, todos os elementos presentes no array nomes sejam exibidos um embaixo do outro após o clique, e não todos na mesma linha como está acontecendo no momento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="nome" value="insira o nome" onfocus="this.value='';"/>
    <button onClick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>

    <div class="exibir">
        <ul id="lista">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>

var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];

//criar elemento para cada campo
const elemDie = document.createElement('li')
const elemGab = document.createElement('li')
const elemLuc = document.createElement('li')

//cada elemento recebe o seu conteúdo referente ao vetor nomes
elemDie.innerHTML = nomes[0]
elemGab.innerHTML = nomes[1]
elemLuc.innerHTML = nomes[2]


        //adicionar cada elemento na lista
lista.appendChild(elemDie)
lista.appendChild(elemGab)
lista.appendChild(elemLuc)

//função para adicionar mais um nome à lista
        function adicionar(){
            var coleta = document.getElementById("nome")
            nomes.push(nome.value)//inserindo o elemento digitado dentro do array nomes
            var nomeDig = document.createElement('li')
            nomeDig.innerHTML = nomes
            lista.appendChild(nomeDig)

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3):

O problema no seu código é que ao fazer **`nomeDig.innerHTML = nomes`** vc está inserindo o array no Html, ao invés de apenas mais um nome. Dei uma pequena melhorada no seu código pois estava muito engessado como pode ver no exemplo abaixo:

```js
var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];

for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
  var lis = document.createElement('li');
  lis.innerHTML = nomes[i];
  lista.appendChild(lis);
}

//função para adicionar mais um nome à lista
function adicionar() {
  var coleta = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var nomeDig = document.createElement('li');

  nomes.push(coleta);
  nomeDig.innerHTML = coleta;
  lista.appendChild(nomeDig);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nome" value="insira o nome" onfocus="this.value='';" />
<button onClick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>

<div class="exibir">
  <ul id="lista"></ul>
</div>
```